# I seem to be unable to assign things

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, text

I'm trying to write a text adventure. At the beginning, it asks whether a person is male or female. If they input "male", I want it to use the words him, his and he. if they input "female", I want it to use the words her and she etc.

```
print ("Is that person male or female?")
gender = input ()
if gender == "male":
    1 = his
    2 = he
    3 = him
else:
    1 = her
    2 = she
    3 = her
```

I want the words to show up when I put in the numbers for example:

```
print (2,"went with", 3,)
```

This should say `"he went with him"`, or `"she went with her"`, But it doesn't.

Comment: `1`, `2` and `3` are not valid [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) in Python

Comment: "This should say something, but it doesn't." That's an understatement for a syntax error. Anyway, you're also going to have to put `his` etc in quotes because right now it expects to find a variable called `his`, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
gender = input("Is that person male or female? ")
if gender == "male":
    one = "his"
    two = "he"
    three = "him"
else:
    one = "her"
    two = "she"
    three = "her"
print(one+' item that '+two+' had was for '+three)
```

This is an example of how it could look like.

Answer (score 0):

Python variable name rules:

> 1. Must begin with a letter (a - z, A - B) or underscore (_)
> 2. Other characters can be letters, numbers or _
> 3. Case Sensitive
> 4. Can be any (reasonable) length
> 5. There are some reserved words which you cannot use as a variable name because Python uses them for other things.

from [here](http://www.w3resource.com/python/python-variable.php)

Comment: Note that these are for 2.x not 3.x, which is a little freer with the definition of a letter (you can `from math import pi as π`, for example!)